# How to imitate a Kendo grid's popup edition dialog?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When a grid's edition mode is set to "popup", it automatically generates a dialog box to let the user modify the editable fields of the selected row.

Using the grid's "update" method, the values are then persisted in the DB and if the PHP handler routine returns the newly updated row, the grid will magically display the properly modified values of the targeted row while keeping it selected !

**MY NEED**: I must do the exact same thing but with a self made edition dialog(kendoWindow).
 I cannot use the one automatically generated by the grid. (For lots of very good reasons...)

Once closed, my self made edition dialog calls an AJAX routine that persists the data in the DB and returns the newly modified row.

How can i update the grid's dataSource with the PHP returned values and while keeping the targeted row selected ?

NOTE: The Grid's row can only be updated after the "update" call to the PHP server returns since some of the values are modified in the PHP code... values that are displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fit your needs, but you can change the popup editor by using the [editable.template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-editable.template) setting. That might let you customize the popup to do whatever else you need it to do.

---

To select a row you need to locate the `<tr>` element and pass it to `.select()` on the grid widget. If you happen to know the UID generated by the DataSource, then you can do:

```
var rowElement = $(gridWidget.element).find('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
gridWidget.select(rowElement);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to programmatically select a row based on a field value... which would simply be the id of the record associated ? (It is part of the grid !)  Once my update PHP call returns, i would simply reload the grid and re-select the same row that was just modified !

Comment: I know we cannot use de "uid" since it will no longer be the same once the grid gets refreshed.

Comment: I added some more to my answer on selecting a row.

Comment: The uid is maintained by the DataSource, so if you can use `DataSource.add(newRecord);` to add your new row, then the uids won't change. If you are completely reloading the data, then yes it will change. However you could use a row or cell template to put your own ID in the row elements somewhere so that you can locate it again.

Comment: I already have some unique identifier which is the ID of the record the row represents...  How can i select based on that ?.

Comment: I would just put a column template http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template on the 1st column, with something like `<span id="${ID}">${data}</span>` then you can get to the row with jQuery: `$("#" + id).closest("tr");`